# The bean 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource could not be registered

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

I'm getting the below error after implementing SecurityFilterChain in one of the Microservices project.

The bean 'springSecurityFilterChain', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/reactive/ReactiveOAuth2ResourceServerJwkConfiguration$WebSecurityConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

SecurityConfig.java Class-

```
package com.mservice.rating.service.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {

        security
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();

        return security.build();
    }
}
```

Pom.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mservice.rating.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>RatingService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RatingService</name>
    <description>This is rating service to store rating related informations</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.yml-

```
server:
  port: 8083

spring:
  application:
    name: RATING-SERVICE
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017
      database: microservices
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:http://localhost:8085

okta:
  oauth2:
    issuer: https://dev-23279260.okta.com/oauth2/default
    audience: api://default
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` dependency?

Comment: Yes, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You defined servlet security in a reactive application. That won't work. Either make it a servlet app (add a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web`) or provide a `SecurityWebFilterChain` (instead of `SecurityFilterChain`).

Also, as mentioned by @marcus-hert-da-coregio in comments, you should be using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` (instead  of `spring-boot-starter-security`).

Comment: Tried but no luck, still getting the same error.

Comment: What did you try exactly? Switching to servlet app? Switching to reactive application? What were the exact errors?

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved after changing `spring-boot-starter-webflux` dependency to `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is basically one of the options in my answer: make it a servlet app. Maybe should you have upvoted & accepted it instead of posting a copycat...